# cant figure out why "Contains" will not work. I am getting an error asking if i am missing a directory or assembly reference.?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
Console.Write("Enter letter grade for class #{0}\n" +
   "(use A, B, C, D or F. Type 0 after all classes entered.): ", counter += 1);
char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (!"ABCDF".ToCharArray().Contains(userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter valid letter");
    continue; // Start's the do loop over 
}
```

Why does `Contains` give me an error asking if i am missing a directory or assembly reference?

Comment: read the error again.  it is not asking if you are missing a *directory*

Comment: directive* my mistake..

Comment: well, are you missing a *`using directive`*?

Comment: I am very new at this, I dont know what that means..

Comment: Look at the top of your file. There's a bunch of `using System;`, etc, up there. You're missing `using System.Linq;`. You can't use the LINQ extension methods without first telling C# that you want to use them.

Comment: I got it to work..Thanks everyone for all of your help!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of converting the string to char[], you can do this:

```
 if(!"ABCDF".Contains(userInput))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter valid letter");
 }
```

Comment: that had an error with converting 'char' to 'string'

Comment: For me it is working just fine, but you can change it to userInput.ToString()